In a metric space $(X,d)$ , if we fix $O∈X$ , for two random points we can always find a third one more distant from $O$ than the other two?
I am trying to prove that in a metric space $(X,d)$, if we fix $O\in X$, for two random points we can always find a third one more distant from $O$ than the other two.
I think this is the same as proving the upper bound property in the proof that $(X, \color{red}\leq)$ is a directed set, where $\color{red}\leq$  is defined as:
$$A \color{red}\leq B $$
$$ \iff d(A,O) \leq d(B,O)$$
.
I tried to resolve it for $X=\mathbb R^2$ and the usual distance on $\mathbb R^2$.
I figured out that $\overrightarrow{OA} - \overrightarrow{OB} $ is a good candidate for an upper bound of $A$ and $B$ in case $sign (x_A,x_B)=-1$ and $sign (y_A,y_B)=-1$ ($sign$ returns $-1$ when signs are opposite and $1$ when signs are identical). I took $O$ as the origin (in order to avoid carrying a $-x_0$ and a $-y_0$ all along the way).
Else, $\overrightarrow{OA} + \overrightarrow{OB} $ is a right candidate for an upper bound of $A$ and $B$.
So, I tried to prove it analytically. It went good for for the case $sign (x_A,x_B)=-1$ and $sign (y_A,y_B)=-1$.
On the other hand, it gets a bit messy for the case $sign (x_A,x_B)=1$ or $sign (y_A,y_B)=1$.
We should have $$ (x_A + x_B)^2 + (y_A + y_B)^2 \geq {x_A} ^2 + {y_A} ^2$$ (and an analog inequality for point $B$, but let's focus on this one for $A$).
It gives: $$ {x_B}^2 + {y_B}^2 \geq -2 (x_A x_B + y_A y_B) \tag{1}$$
.
Since we have $sign (x_A,x_B)=1$ or $sign (y_A,y_B)=1$ I took, for example the case where $sign (x_A,x_B)=1$ and $sign (y_A,y_B)=-1$.
But then, there are two subcases again: either $x_A x_B + y_A y_B \geq 0$ (in which case the inequality is satisfied), either $x_A x_B + y_A y_B < 0$ in which case it seems a bit more difficult to fit the inequality.
So far, I am stuck in this case: $x_A x_B + y_A y_B < 0$.
I was thinking about rewriting $(1)$ as $$ \frac{{OB}^2}{2} \geq - \overrightarrow{OA}.\overrightarrow{OB}$$
where . stands for the dot product.

This is not true. Take $X = \{0,1\}$ with the discrete distance. If $O = 0$, $A= 0$ and $B = 1$, then $d(0, A) = 0$, $d(O, B) = 1$ but there is no point $X$ such that $d(O, X) > 1$.

Thanks for your counterexample. Yet, can we say it is true on the metric space $\mathbb R ^2$ with the usual distance on $\mathbb R ^2$ ?

This is trivially true in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $a = d(0,A)$, $b = d(0, B)$, and $c > \max(a,b)$. Then any point on the circle of radius $r$ centered in $0$ will do the job.

If we take $X=B$ don't we  actually have $A \color{red}\leq X$ and $ B\color{red}\leq X$ ? (since $d(O,A)= 0 \leq d(O,X) = 1$)

This is no different from saying

In a metric space, for a point $O$, and for any other point $S$, there is a point $T$ such that $d(T,O)>d(S,O)$.

(This is because if you have two points $A$ and $B$, pick the one farther from $O$ and use the statement above with that as $S$.)
This statement is not true in general, and a simple example is the discrete metric on any set (with at least two points). In general, any compact metric space works (since it is bounded, and there are two "farthest" points). But this statement is true for any unbounded metric space, in particular, $\Bbb R^n$ with the usual metric, since the entire metric space cannot be contained in the sphere centred at $O$ and passing through $S$.
Hope this helps. :)
